# Navigate to existing page in History instead of reloading that page by accessing the link

Tags: javascript, html

I look for a method to access pages already loaded in History. If a page was visited in the past `css` can recognize it and therefore we can set custom styles for visited links. I don't know a similar option in `javascript`, but it should exist. Meanwhile, if page is found in History I also need it's position in order to be able to set `history.go(currentPosition)` var.

It may be some other way for the same need, which is to avoid page reloading its resources especially the scripts because I need to be able to use the variables modified in those scripts. The following example can show better what I mean:

Put the next 3 files in the same folder, then access the initial page, `index.html`. You can see that by navigating in `History` the page is not reloaded and the variables are mentained in memory. That is what I need!

file: `index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Initial page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>This is initial page</h3>
        <p>In the next div we have a running timer by updating a variable in the loaded script:</p>
        <div id="output"><p></p></div>
        <a href="another.html">Navigate to another page</a>
        <script id="pageScript">
            const output = document.querySelector('#output p');
            output.innerHTML = 'Script loaded...';
            let temp = 0;
            setInterval(() => {
                temp++;
                output.innerHTML = 'Time elapsed: ' + temp + ' seconds.';
            }, 1000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

file: `another.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Another Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>This is another page</h3>
        <p>Test the following links to see the difference:</p>
        <a href="javascript:history.back()"> &lt;&lt; Back</a>
        <br>
        <a href="index.html">Regular link to initial page</a>
        <br>
        <a href="last.html">Regular link to last page</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

file: `last.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Last Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>This is last page</h3>
        <p>Test the following links to see the difference:</p>
        <a href="javascript:history.back()"> &lt;&lt; Back</a>
        <br>
        <a href="index.html">Regular link to initial page</a>
        <br>
        <a href="javascript:history.go(-2)"> &lt;&lt; Back &lt;&lt; Back</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it fair to say that you intend to keep a timer running irrespective of where the user is on one of your pages?

If the only intention is to maintain the timer across all pages, you can surely store the start time of the user in [Local Storage or Session Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) and then calculate the time elapsed using current time.

Comment: Ofcourse not, is not my only intention to mantain a timer but a whole script with tons of vars :) This example just shows that the page is not reloaded when accessed in History.